# What are methods of increasing the protein content of garden vegetables?

Tags: vegetables, nutrients

I read a random article about the effects of a certain fertilizer on tomatoes and how it happened to increase the protein content of the tomatoes relative to other fertilizers ([1](http://www.popsci.com/environment/article/2009-09/fertilizer-future-might-be-closer-we-think), [2](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/jf9018917)) and it piqued my interest.  I've also read that wheat grown at certain parts of the year have more protein content as well.

Aside from choosing to grow lentils or some other high-protein plant, what are the methods of increasing the protein content of your garden edibles?  If they vary by plant family group, then what are the methods that work for different family groups?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Aside from some sort of hormone type application, I would think you just need to make sure they have enough Nitrogen.  It is the Nitrogen that forms Amino Acids, which then build protein.

Comment: Supporting articles [Grain Protein Content and N Needs](http://www.ext.colostate.edu/pubs/crops/00555.html) and [Organic Materials as Nitrogen Fertilizers](http://www.ext.colostate.edu/pubs/crops/00546.html)

Comment: Don't overbalance the nitrogen.  It will just result in more stems and leaves, and less fruit.